# Adding through iteration

Tags: python, iteration, addition

I want to take user input and add each number up to 0. For example `user inputs 9` I want to add 9+8+7+6.... +1 and output the total. My code

```
def main(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        sum = i + (i - 1)
    return sum

result = main(9)
print(result)
```

comes close, but I can't get it to iterate through until 0. I've tried adding ranges in a few ways but no luck there. I'm stuck.

Comment: Use `for i in range(args + 1):` and then `summ = summ + i`. I used `summ` because `sum` is an in built function. Apart from your function, you can simply use the in-built `sum` function as `sum(range(args + 1))` where `range(args+1)` will generate numbers from `0` to `arg`

Comment: This is giving error `can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple`

Comment: Ok, replace `for i in range(args + 1):` by `for i in range(args[0] + 1):`

Comment: Thank you to all that have contributed. I am a beginner but this was all very helpful. These will be great reference notes going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the user input is assigned to `x`, then the most simplistic answer is:

```
sum(range(int(x)+1))
```

Note that `range()` will generate a list (actually, an immutable sequence type in Python 3) of numbers up to, but not including, `x`, hence the `+1`.

In terms of your original code, there are a few issues. First, you should avoid naming variables the same as Python built-ins, such as `sum`. Second, you are attempting to iterate through a tuple of input arguments (e.g. `args = (9,)` in your case), which will perform `9 + (9-1)`, or otherwise `17` and then return that sum as an output.

Instead, you could do something like:

```
def main(*args):
    mysum = 0
    for i in range(args[0]+1):
        mysum = mysum + i
    return mysum

result = main(9)

print(result)
```

Both solutions here will return `45`.

Comment: I didn't downvote but perhaps you can also add whats wrong in OP's code so as to teach him/her. The OP seems to be a beginner. It's a nice way of teaching by explaining the problems in the code

Comment: Sure thing, I will add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: pedantic I know, but `range` doesn't actually return a list (at least not in Python 3)

Answer (score 2):

Nth triangle number. No iteration needed.

```
def calculate_nth_triangle_number(value):
    return value * (value + 1) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code misuses a relatively advanced feature of Python, that is argument packing, where all the arguments supplied to a function are packed in a tuple.

What happens when you call `main(9)`? the loop is entered once (because calling the function with a single argument is equivalent to `args = (9, )` in the body of the function) `i` takes only one value, `i = 9` and you have `sum = 9+8 = 17`.

For your case I don't like a `for` loop,  can you use a `while` loop? with a `while` your function follows exactly the definition of your task!

```
def my_sum(n):
    result = 0
    while n>0:
        result = result + n
        n = n - 1
    return result
```

Note that the order of summation and decrease is paramount to a correct result... note also that `sum` is the name of a built-in function and it is considered bad taste to overload a built-in name with an expression of yours.

Comment: This makes alot of sense to me and is reminiscent of unsuccessful attempts within my last few tries. I do have one question though. In the  `result = result + n` line would it be possible to combine that with `n-1` or is it best to keep them separate for the sake of the loop?

Comment: I suspect that what you have in mind is `result = result + n--` ... I'm sorry but Python has not an unary  decrement operator :-).

Comment: Ok. I did study some c++ before learning python so I think I'm just confusing the two

Comment: BTW, _"This makes alot of sense to me"_ it's because I've written my answer so that it made sense to you, in the context of your question (something that I wouldn't say of other answers ;-)